# Can I make floated div margin values relative?

Tags: css

div1 is floated left so div2 comes up beside it. If I want to add a 10px left margin on div2, why do I need to set it to 60px? ie. the width of div1 + 10px. Can I make div2 relative to div1 so I can set the div2 left margin to 10px?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #div1{
                width: 50px;
                float: left;
            }
            #div2 {
                margin-left: 60px;
            }
            #div1, #div2{
                border: 1px solid red;
            }
        </style>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div>
            <div id="div1">
                div1
            </div>
            <div id="div2">
                div2
            </div>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</html>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7DGK/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `float: left` for #div2.

Comment: What is the difference between display:inline-block; and float:left; ?

Comment: This answer seems to be more correct. Using inline-block has some quirks. For example, you can't precisely control the gap between a series of inline-block elements. eg. You can't easily have a 0px gap.

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: You need to use -ve margins to correct for a gap which may be different in different browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Floats break the element out of the document flow.  The reason you need to add the left margin at 60px is to have it clear the left floated div... if you want them both inline, I'd suggest using:

```
        #div1{
            width: 50px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        #div2 {
            margin-left: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        #div1, #div2{
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

Comment: Does the above cause the borders to collapse for div2?